# check and passing parameter to view in base controller (afterAction)

Tags: php, yii

for controller i want to do some post checkup after action done, and pass back to view.

in controller

```
 $this->render('/Company/index', array("linkArray" => $this->linkArray, "input" => $this->input, "data" => $this->data, "lang" => $this->lang));
```

in controller i already pass  $this->data.

in base controller i declare following function

```
 public function afterAction($action) {

            $checkData = $this->checkData($action->data);

    return parent::afterAction($action);
}
```

1 . how can i pass $checkData to view in afterAction(base controller).

2 .  how can i access $this->data in $action and pass to checkdata function.
i try ->, :: ,[]  ,{} all method to access to its property but its fail

Thx and happy new year.

Comment: when rendering is done, you want to render something else, you can't change value in rendered html(although I guess with jQuery you could :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do this with the beforeRender() function.

These links may help.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/54/